# How to make scrapy follow the url which is generated by javascript?

Tags: python, selenium, web-crawler, scrapy

I want to crawl the news in this website: `new.scut.edu.cn`
But in its subwebsite like [this](http://news.scut.edu.cn/s/22/t/4/p/69/c/7/i/346/list.htm) , the next-page(chinese下一页) url which is in the bottom-right is generated by javascript. The html source code of the next-page is `<a name="_l_p_n" href="javascript:if(true){a_next('/s/22/t/4/p/69/c/7/i//list.htm');}" title="进入下一页">下一页</a>`   , the refer script is

```
var _currentPageIndex =346;
var _listArticleCount =-1;       
var _listPaginationCount =-1; 
function a_next(url) {           
if(_currentPageIndex > 1) {               
location.href =url.replace('i/','i/'+(_currentPageIndex-1));
}                
}
```

I want to crawl all pages, so the spider need to follow the next page. Here is my scrapy spider code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import scrapy
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scutnews.items import ScutnewsItem
from scrapy.http import Request, FormRequest
import re

class NewsSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "scutnews"
    allowed_domain = ["news.scut.edu.cn"]
    start_urls = ["news.scut.edu.cn"]

    rules = (
            Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=(r"http://news.scut.edu.cn/s/22/t/.+/list.*"))),
            Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=(r"http://news.scut.edu.cn/s/22/t/.+/info.*")), callback = "parse_item")
            )

    def start_requests(self):
        yield FormRequest("http://news.scut.edu.cn", headers={'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:37.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/37.0'})

    def parse_item(self, response):
        sel = Selector(response)
        item = ScutnewsItem()
       # item['title'] = sel.xpath('//div[@class="display_news_con"]/h1/text()').extract()
       # item['time'] = sel.xpath('//span[@class="posttime"]/text()').extract()
        item['content'] = sel.xpath('//div[@class="infobox"]/div[1]/p/text()|//div[@class="infobox"]/div[1]/p/span/text()|//div[@class="infobox"]/div[1]/p/span/span/text()|//div[@class="infobox"]/div[1]/p/span/span/span/text()|//div[@class="infobox"]/div[1]/text()').extract()
       # item['url'] = response.url
        return item
```

I find that the current page url is only one number different from the next page url.
I know there are some solutions,simulate the javascript logic or use the library like selenium and phantomjs. How can I fix the scrapy spider code to follow the next page, in the way of simulating the js logic? Need to change the scrapy spider rule? What about in the way of selenium or phantomjs?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Hint: `scrapyjs` middleware can be very helpful here, no need to involve a real browser.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to propose a way without rendering javascript, but extracting the javascript information from the page.

You could add a `parse_list` callback to your `Rule` following `list-pages`

```
rules = (
    Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=(r"http://news.scut.edu.cn/s/22/t/.+/list.*")), callback = "parse_list"),
    Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=(r"http://news.scut.edu.cn/s/22/t/.+/info.*")), callback = "parse_item")
)
```

and implement in the callback a regex to parse `javascript` and get the total number of pages (of the list):

```
def parse_list(self, response):
    sel = Selector(response)
    xpath_pageCounter = './/script[@language="javascript" and contains(.,"currentPageIndex")]'
    pageCounter = sel.xpath(xpath_pageCounter).re(r'currentPageIndex =(\d+);')
    if pageCounter:
        page_Number = int(pageCounter[0]) - 1
        page_url = response.url.replace('/list.htm', '/i/' + str(page_Number) + '/list.htm')
        print '#####', response.url, page_Number, page_url
        yield scrapy.FormRequest(page_url, callback=self.parse_item)
```

If there is a `page_Number` you could create all the page number links (down to the first page) in a loop and pass those `requests` to the crawler.

THE CODE SHOWN ABOVE DOES NOT WORK, but can serve as starting point.